# Problem with ASP.net URL

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to rewrite:

`Test.php` to `Default.asp`

So I use the rule:

`<rewrite url="~/Test.php" to="~/default.asp" />`

But that rule gives a 404.

However this rule works fine:

`<rewrite url="~/default.aspx" to="~/default.asp" />`

But this rule 404's:

`<rewrite url="~/Test" to="~/default.asp" />`

**My web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="rewriter"
                 requirePermission="false"
                 type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
    </configSections>

    <system.web>

        <httpModules>
            <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
        </httpModules>

    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>

        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule" />
        </modules>

        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    </system.webServer>

    <rewriter>
        <rewrite url="~/Test.php" to="~/default.asp" />
    </rewriter>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is PHP being handled by?

Per [the setup documentation](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/installation/windows-server-2003) you need to ensure that the PHP extension is being handled by ASP.NET. In addition, if IIS is checking to see if the file exists before handing it off to ASP.NET you'd potentially be missing this as well.

Also, based on your system.webServer addition (which isn't detailed on the module's site), can we assume Server 2008? If so, can I recommend [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) instead?